# I have a text I am trying to make a Parser, best way to do it?

Tags: python

I have a text file:

```
if x < 5 then
{
 BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
}
else
{
  BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
}
fi
```

I want my python code to read this, and let me know if the syntax is correct:
I am not sure if regEx is good. but if there is any other way.

Comment: You can read about the python syntax here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements.

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, you're asking. You're creating a parser? If so, where is your parsing code? Where are you stuck? What is expected vs actual output? As written, it's not clear, and it's also very broad (e.g. there are lots of ways to create a parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `python` definitely has what you are asking for.

Just look at the syntaxes at any of the python starter resource like a tutorial or even official docs.
Here is the syntax for what you are asking.

```
if x < 5:
    # Code to be executed when condition matches.
    pass  # Remove this when there's actual code.
else:  # You can also have elif here for non-overlapping conditions and with condition precedences.
    # Code to be executed otherwise ie. when the first condition fails.
    pass
```

Comment: Please re-read the OP's question. They're not asking about an `if` block. They want to construct a parser that *parses* an `if` block. A question that's very broad (and off-topic).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Well I re-read it multiple times, and this is the best I could conceive. I tried to answer that, and if/when the question is modified to be able to convey the actual problem better, I will update the answer. I don't mind your downvote :) though.